# Synchronize event for multiple users using a web application in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization, game-center

I struck with a problem. I am working on a game development using C#, ASP.net web application using MVC4 and Entity Framework.

To brief my problem:
           I have a web application with a single page with a slider range from 0-100.
Consider 3 users logs in the application and each are in their own session accessing the page with the slider.

Say if,  user 1 moves the slider from position 0 to 10, the slider corresponding to the user 2 and user 3 has to be synchronized and should get reflected to their UI. vice versa for all. Looks like a multiplayer gaming where the vent of one gets shown for other users.

How to make this happen? I am trying hard cracking my mind to implement it but couldn't. 
Pls help me out fellow.
Please do let me know more further information.
I appreciate your help.
Looking forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this on a web app only, without using any kind of technology such as Flash, Silverlight, Java Applet, etc will necessarily involve something similar to [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) also seems like a good alternative. I linked an example from Scott Hanselman's blog.

Comment: Icarus,Thanks a lot for the information. It was really helpful. And the blog was so helpful to get my hands dirty with SignalR. Can you give thought on implementing andt he time takes to implement. I need to submit this task in a week. Is a week affordable for this. Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/) is exactly what you are looking for:

> Async signaling library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications

Comment: Thanks a lot Oded. I appreciate your help. I got a new stuff to look on. Can you give your thought on implementation. Way of using SignalR to my application in synchronizing the vent for muliple users in different session? Does thread is needed? since when both users access the same resource. Looking forward for your thought on this. Thanks in nadvance